# Fortran not writing to output file or printing to screen

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I wrote this simple Fortran code with the intention of the answer being written to an output file. Instead, the output file is blank, and even when I attempt to print to the screen, it doesn't do that either.

Here is the code, it is pretty short:

```
    program FTCS
    implicit none
    integer :: m,n,i,j,a=1
    real, allocatable :: P(:,:)
    real :: r,l,t,delta_x,delta_t,g

    open(20,file='input.txt')
    open(30,file='outputFTCS.txt')
    read(20,2)n  ! reading these values from the input.txt file
    read(20,3)r,t,delta_t,l  ! reading these values from input.txt
    
    2 format (T10,I6)  ! I is for integers
    3 format (T10,F15.8)  ! F is for real (float)
    
    delta_x = 1/(n-1)  ! n = points
    g = floor(t/delta_t)
    m = g  ! time
    
    allocate (P(m,n))
    P(1,:)=20  ! initial condition: indexing begins at 1
    
    do i=2,m    ! points
        P(i,1)=100 ! boundary condition (left)
        P(i,n)=0  ! boundary condition (right)
        do j=2,n-1  ! time
            P(i,j)=r*(P(i-1,j+1)+P(i-1,j-1))+(1-2*r)*(P(i-1,j))  ! T_i=r(T_i-1 + T_i+1) + (1-2r)T_i
            print *,"hello"
        end do
    end do
    
    do i=1,m
        print *,'hello'
        
    end do
    
    10 format(10f10.2)
    30 format (10f10.2)
    
    close(10)  ! do this last
    close(30)

    end program FTCS
```

I compiled using `gfortran FTCS.f90` and then tried to run using the following: `./FTCS` or `./a.out` and neither produced an output. I have also compiled with `gfortran FTCS.f90 -o` to achieve the same result.

The input.txt file is just

```
    n=10     
    r=0.25     
    t=.03     
    delta_t=0.005     
    l=1
```

Why isn't it writing to the output file, or even writing anything to the screen?

Comment: What happens if you put `print *, n` and `print *, r ,t,delta_t,l` right after you read the values from the file?

Comment: The format `(T10,F15.8)` looks unsuitable for reading the parts of the input file you ask it to. Are you sure there are no error messages and you get the input values you expect?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Notice that you never reference unit 30, which is your output file. How do you expect the program to write anything to  anything to this file?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a couple issues here. First your input file not only has numbers it has characters. If you change the input file to look like:

```
10
0.25
.03
0.005
1
```

And your code to look like:

```
    program FTCS
    implicit none
    integer :: m,n,i,j,a=1
    real, allocatable :: P(:,:)
    real :: r,l,t,delta_x,delta_t,g

    open(20,file='input.txt')
    open(30,file='outputFTCS.txt')
    read(20,*)n  ! reading these values from the input.txt file
    read(20, *) r, t, delta_t, l

write(*,*) n, r, t, delta_t, l


end program
```

You'll notice that it works now:

```
:~/work/random$ ./a.out
          10  0.250000000       2.99999993E-02   4.99999989E-03   1.00000000
```

If you want to keep the `n=` you'll have to read the line as characters and then do some splitting to extract exactly what you need.

Comment: The format in the question uses the `T` edit descriptor, the purpose of which is to skip over the character part of the input. There's no need to do anything special for "splitting to extract" and certainly no need to "read the line as characters". What is necessary, of course, is to skip the correct number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

The T10 specifier makes the first reading from position 10 and after. But in your file input.txt there is nothing there.